# Changing position in table so title is always on top in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I've made some changes and progress hence the new question (this way it can be simplified). I'm creating a layout where images will alternate positions, left and right on the page with information opposite them (on desktop). I'm using `flex` for alignment and so the contents of each DIV is centered within it.

My code is as follows…

```css
.site-section-content {
    width: 100%;
}

.site-section-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: dashed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.site-section-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: dashed;
}
}

.site-section-title-section {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.site-section-title-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
}

.site-section-info-section {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.site-section-info-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<div class="site-section-content">
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-section-wrap">
      <div class="site-section-info-section">
         <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="site-section-title-section">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For clarity I've added dashed borders which will be removed. You'll notice that the height is the same on desktop for each side but on mobile it's only the height of its contents, this behaviour is fine.

I've swapped around the tags for each alternation but the problem is that the image title and info isn't always above the image on mobile (which it should be).

I've experimented with different float positions to no avail so I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just use flex , no need of float for your requirement,
2. don't repeat the property in media query which you don't need to change

```css
    .site-section-content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .site-section-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        background: pink;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-flow: row;
        text-align: center;
        border-style: dashed;
    }

    .site-section-title-section {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .site-section-info-section {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .site-section-content .site-section-wrap:nth-child(even){
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
        .site-section-wrap {
            flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
        }
        .site-section-title-section,.site-section-info-section{
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="site-section-content">
        <div class="site-section-wrap">
            <div class="site-section-title-section">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="site-section-info-section">
                <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-section-wrap">
            <div class="site-section-title-section">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="site-section-info-section">
                <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-section-wrap">
            <div class="site-section-title-section">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="site-section-info-section">
                <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-section-wrap">
            <div class="site-section-title-section">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/540x250" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="site-section-info-section">
                <h1>IMAGE INFO</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems like this will work so I've accepted the answer. I will test this soon. I tend to repeat media queries so code is easier to read and edit.